# Prevent Visual Studio C++ console exit immediately without system("pause") or extra get

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I know there have been many work around proposed for immediate shutdown, but I was wondering if there is other way to do so for cross platform?

I think `system("pause")` is visual studio / windows specific and `getchar()` or other similar stuff that waits for users' input create unnecessary input for exiting the program running under say gcc.

Any idea?

-- Edit -- 
I also tried hitting `Ctrl+F5`, but it doesn't work sometimes. So I'm looking for an alternative command (if there's any) or setup that can pause the console screen in visual studio and doesn't cause any discrepancy in other c++ compilers.

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: Run code in a command-prompt/shell?

Comment: Do you want something like a 5 second delay before shutting down?

Comment: @MatsPetersson If you run the code in a separate shell you will lose the debug capabilities of Visual Studio

Comment: http://russelrayphotos.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/hit-any-key-framed.jpg

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));` will make it sleep for 1 second. It's cross-platform. Otherwise why not use `std::cin.get()`? which is also cross-platform.

Comment: because if I compile it under gcc and run in under shell, `cin.get()` will prompt another input before exiting the program.

Comment: Do you want to pause while running through Visual Studio (like setting a breakpoint right at the end of the application before it is closed), or when running in "release mode"?

Answer (score 4):

This problem only occurs when you launch a console program from a GUI. So there is a very simple cross-platform workaround -- run console programs from a console. If you want to make a program that runs well from a GUI, make a GUI program.

The other suggested workarounds are awful. Both `getchar()` and `system("pause")` interfere with any attempt to use the program as a filter or to redirect its input and output. It doesn't make sense to break a program so that it works "correctly" when used incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

u can use this method
after that u write the last code of your program(before return 0;) u can use for example ( cin >> x;  ) command..
 then the program will wait for u to enter new data. and u can see your answer in debugging program :D..
good luck with this trick :D